# iphone refresh viewcontroller not working when app enters foreground

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller, background-foreground

i have an application with 3 tabs inbox,contacts and settings.

In inbox, there is a list of messages from other users ,i update the messages using a function `reloadTableViewDataSource`, now i have to reload or refresh the messages when the application enters the foreground.

To achieve this,i have given the following code in appdelegate.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
    Inbox *inbox=[[Inbox alloc]init];
    inbox.userid=self.usermail; 
    inbox.password=self.password;
    inbox.loggedInUserId=self.loggedinUserId;
    [inbox reloadTableViewDataSource];

}
```

the updated method seems to be called as i am seeing the `nslog` messages about update but nothing is actually happening in the inbox viewcontroller,the new messages coming are not refreshed, what is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: What does the code for reloadTableViewDataSource look like?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't forget to release your `Inbox` instance.

Comment: that is too long to paste it here.well it contains a webservice to get the latest messges and it reloads tableview .my doubt is if i create a new instance of inbox viewcontroller and call the update function from it ,then would the messages in the original viewcontroller instance be refreshed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you create a new Inbox object and refresh its content.
But what you really want is to refresh the data of your Inbox object which is currently displayed.

So what you need to do, is holding a reference to the Inbox object which is used in your ViewController. And invoke reloadTableViewDataSource on that reference.

hope thats the problem...